# Make Oracle SQL Developer execute the SELECT statement every time in a loop

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, select, plsql

I need to create a table with random values from another table. For that, I tried using a `LOOP` that collects random `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME` from the other table and puts them in my table.

But using a LOOP does not work as the `SELECT` statement does not execute more than once.

```
BEGIN
LOOP
v_counter:=v_counter+1;
SELECT fname INTO v_fname FROM users SAMPLE (5) WHERE some_condition AND ROWNUM=1;
SELECT lname INTO v_lname FROM users SAMPLE (5) WHERE some_condition AND ROWNUM=1;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_fname2);
EXIT WHEN (v_counter > 50);
END LOOP;
END;
```

I get the same name printed 50 times.

Comment: what do you mean by *SELECT statement does not execute more than once.* ? How many time should it get executed ?

Comment: 50 times to return 50 different results

Comment: So, what's wrong in your code ?? it will print 50 times.. Now, if your table contains different records then only you can expect different result.

Comment: How many records in `users` tables?

Comment: Can you share declare section of your block?

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with SQL Developer.

Answer (score 2):

The code in OP:

```
BEGIN
LOOP
v_counter:=v_counter+1;
SELECT fname INTO v_fname FROM users SAMPLE (5) WHERE some_condition AND ROWNUM=1;  --Line_no a
SELECT lname INTO v_lname FROM users SAMPLE (5) WHERE some_condition AND ROWNUM=1;  --Line_no b
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_fname2); --Line_no c
EXIT WHEN (v_counter > 50);
END LOOP;
END;
```

Issues:

If we see, `Line_No a` is selecting the data in variable `v_fname` and `Line_no c` which is printing is printing another variable `v_fname2`. I dont understand, a variable which you are not changing the value, why are you expecting to see the result in print changed? You see, `v_fname` and `v_fname2` are TWO DIFFERENT VARIABLES. You are assigning the values to `v_fname` and not `v_fname2`, while you are printing `v_fname2` and not `v_fname`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather use an implicit `FOR LOOP`:

```
BEGIN
  FOR x in (
     SELECT a.fname, b.lname FROM users SAMPLE (5) a, users SAMPLE (5) b  WHERE some_condition AND ROWNUM < 51
  ) LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(x.fname||' - '||x.lname);
  END LOOP;
END;
```